Approximation for the generalized First-Order Marcum Q-Function
I want to approximate the first-order Marcum Q-function $Q_{1}(a,b)$. However, the goal is to obtain an acceptable approximation for any values of $a$ and $b$. Is there perhaps a possible solution for this? Thank you in advance for your help.
